# Modifying django-allauth error messages on a signup form

Tags: python, django, jinja2, django-allauth, django-crispy-forms

I'm currently building a website that makes use of `django-allauth` and I've come across a problem regarding error messages while using a custom User model.

My custom User model is called `CustomUser`, I've noticed that when `django-allauth` handles errors regarding the username, it uses the name of the user model as the starting word to the error message's sentence. Example image is linked below.

[Image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2nfU.png)

How can I change this error message? I'd like to stay away from overriding any `django-allauth` views if possible, though I'd be happy with any solution!

This is my Django form code that makes use of `django-crispy-forms`:

```py
        <form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
              {{ form.email|attr:"autofocus"|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
              {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
              {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
              {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
              {{ form.birthday|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
              {{ form.password1|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
              {{ form.password2|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
              {{ form.captcha|as_crispy_field }}
                {% for error in form.captcha.errors %}
                  {% if error %}
                  <style>
                    #div_id_captcha {
                      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
                    }
                  </style>
                  <span class="invalid-feedback d-block mb-3">
                    <strong>
                      You must complete the captcha to register
                    </strong>
                  </span>
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
          {% if redirect_field_value %}
          <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
          {% endif %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-light mb-3">Register <i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-fw"></i></button>

          <p>Already have an account?<br /><small><a href="{{ login_url }}">Login here</a></small></p>
        </form>
```